# Dynamically refer to different type of variables in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Here I want to simplify my c++ code from version 2 to version 1. In a language like Python, it's simple to refer to a different types of variables like version 1. How can I achieve similar code in c++?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/* version 1: compile failed */
void display(std::vector<int> vi, std::vector<double> vd) {
  // error: operands to ?: have different types
  // ‘std::vector<double>’ and ‘std::vector<int>’
  auto& v = vi.empty() ? vd : vi;
  for (const auto &e : v) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
}

/* version 2 */
void display(std::vector<int> vi, std::vector<double> vd) {
  if (!vi.empty()) {
    for (const auto &e : vi) {
      std::cout << e << " ";
    }
  } else {
    for (const auto &e : vd) {
      std::cout << e << " ";
    }
  }
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> vi{0, 1, 2};
  std::vector<double> vd{10., 11, 12};

  // one of vi, vd can be empty after some modifications
  ...

  display(vi, vd);
  return 0;
}
```

Supplement:

Here the print function is only an example. My main purpose is to create a reference to `std::vector<int>` or `std::vector<double>` according to whether they are empty or not. The following example may

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void process_1(std::vector<int> v) {
  for (const auto &e : v) {
    std::cout << e << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void process_1(std::vector<double> v) {
  double sum = 0;
  for (const auto &e : v) {
    sum += e;
  }
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}

void process_2(std::vector<int>) {
  //...
}

void process_2(std::vector<double>) {
  //...
}

/* Version 2 */
int version_2(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> vi{0, 1, 2};
  std::vector<double> vd{10., 11, 12};

  if (!vi.empty()) {
    process_1(vi);
  } else {
    process_1(vd);
  }

  // do something

  if (!vi.empty()) {
    process_2(vi);
  } else {
    process_2(vd);
  }

  return 0;
}

/* Version 1 */
int version_1(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<int> vi{0, 1, 2};
  std::vector<double> vd{10., 11, 12};

  // in Python, it's easy to create a reference dynamically, eg:
  // ref = vd is len(vi) == 0 else vi
  auto &ref = vd if vi.empty() else vi;

  process_1(ref);
  // do something
  process_2(ref);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A side note: you can pass `vi`, `vd` by `const &` (instead of by value) for efficiency.

Comment: I don't think the duplicate fits. It doesn't provide the workaround OP asked for.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Could you help to explain the mechanism behind it? Is it because the left-hand side of the equation must be a definite type or can be deducted from the right-hand side?

Answer (score 5):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
void display(const std::vector<int>& vi, const std::vector<double>& vd) {
  auto print_sequence = [](const auto& v) {
    for (const auto &e : v) {
      std::cout << e << " ";
    }
  }
  vi.empty() ? print_sequence(vd) : print_sequence(vi);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're searching for is a visitor.

First version:

```
void display(std::vector<int> vi, std::vector<double> vd) {
    auto vis = [](const auto& v) {
        for (const auto& e : v) {
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
    };
    if (vi.empty()) {
        vis(vd);
    } else {
        vis(vi);
    }
}
```

Note however, you don't necessarily need to pass two arguments, you might use a `std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>`:

```
void display(std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector< double>> vv) {
    auto vis = [](const auto& v) {
        for (const auto& e : v) {
            std::cout << e << " ";
        }
    };
    std::visit(vis, vv);
}
```

As a variant is constructible from any of the types, you can simply pass it either `vi` or `vd`.

This works with arbitrary number of types.
Also, suggest passing arguments by `const` reference (e.g., `const std::variant<std::vector< int>, std::vector< double>>&`).

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>`? As written, the `variant`-using version doesn't make sense - it attempts to iterate over a single value of a primitive type.